A movie about a man changing a destiny set in early 20 century in usa
A movie set in early 20 century (perhaps 1930) in USA, made well before 2000. I remember only few scenes and I want to watch it again.
It was about a man traveling across USA helping people fulfill their dreams - a kind of a "destiny" man.
A few scenes which are stuck in my head:
They eat in some highway roadhouse and there is a man ordering dozens of burgers, eating them all to win a bet. But it is revealed, that his wish is to be able to eat a lot of burgers, which, whe fulfilled, turns into a hell as he must bet with people to earn money for food.
Another situation takes place in a city, on an uphill street, someone crosses this street with a bike and passing trucks splash some dirt on him so he starts swearing and wishes not to be this close to the truck, then the destiny man fulfills his wish and a minute later the truck kills him...
I might remember, that this guy is traveling with another guy and he is somehow trying to show him, that his destiny, although it may be poor, can be better, than others... But perhaps the plot is slightly different.
Please help me to find this unknown movie! Thanks

I think I remember some similar movie, but I'm quite sure it played some time in the 80's or 90's. It might have been based on some of King's works, but not 100% sure.

Interstate 60 ? There are extremely similar scenes: man, who can eat enormous/unlimited amount of food, but can't really enjoy his meal; bike accident happens, guy, wishes it never happened, then, when his wish is fulfilled, he avoids the bike, but dies under the truck. On the other hand this movie was released in 2002 and set in modern times, so I'm not 100% sure.

@defaultlocale IMO, Interstate 60 shares way too many similarities with the question for this to be a coincidence, so you should put it up as an answer. It's possible that the OP simply got the time wrong.

@Walt I didn't receive a confirmation from OP and just forgot about this comment. Thank you!

Movie identification questions must contain sufficient detail to be answerable. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions. Identification questions without an accepted answer will be deleted after 14 days.

Interstate 60: Episodes of The Road (2002) has extremely similar scenes. It was released in 2002 and set in modern times, though.
The movie is about Neil Oliver, young artist, who travels by the nonexistent Interstate 60 in the company with O.W. Grant (Gary Oldman), the son of a leprechaun and a Cheyenne Indian. O.W. Grant has the ability to grant wishes.
Similar scenes:

In the highway roadhouse characters meat man, who can eat enormous/unlimited amount of food, but can't really enjoy his meal
In the beginning of the movie O.W.Grant is involved in a bike-car accident. Car owner makes a wish it never happened. When O.W. Grant fulfills his wish, car owner walks out of his car undisturbed and dies under the truck in the middle of the road.

You can watch trailer for Interstate 60 on Youtube:




@Kezon Even if you lost access to your previous account, you might still be able to merge them using the procedure described here. This will also enable you to accept this answer once it turns out to be the correct solution.

@Kezon You're welcome! I'm glad you found the answer.
